# Set event on my own view

Tags: android, events, view

I have my own view with some values. How i can call on click in my control when something happen.

```
myControl = (myMControl ) findViewById(R.id.myControl);
myControl.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I want call in my control(myMControl ) onClick that is in activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to programmatically trigger an onClick for your custom View. 
Do it like this:

```
myControl.performClick();
```